# MYSQL SELECT with custom Function

Tags: mysql, function

I want to be able to select records using custom function in mysql.

I tried the following code but I got null result where there is data:

```
SELECT id, getAmountS(id) FROM product WHERE id=2

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getAmountS(pid INT(11)) RETURNS DOUBLE(12, 2) DETERMINISTIC BEGIN
    DECLARE sellvalue DOUBLE(12, 2) ;
    SELECT
        SUM( CASE WHEN s.invoicestatus = 'Active' THEN ROUND(
        (r.rate * 1 -((r.rate * 1) * r.discount / 100))+((
        r.rate * 1 -( (r.rate * 1) * r.discount / 100)) * r.gstrate / 100),
                2  ) ELSE 0 END) INTO sellvalue FROM  morder r
        LEFT JOIN sale s ON  r.saleid = s.id
        WHERE r.productid = pid;
    RETURN sellvalue;
END $$
```

Please help.

Table: product

```
id(INT), productname(VARCHAR), manufacturer(INT)
```

Table: morder

```
id(INT), saleid(INT), gstrate(INT), rate(DOUBLE), productid(INT), discount(DOUBLE)
```

Table: sale

```
id(INT), invoiceno(VARCHAR), invoicestatus(ENUM), invoiceDate(DATE)
```

The following statement works fine:

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN s.invoicestatus = 'Active' THEN ROUND(
        (r.rate * 1 -((r.rate * 1) * r.discount / 100))+((
        r.rate * 1 -( (r.rate * 1) * r.discount / 100)) * r.gstrate / 100), 2  ) ELSE 0 END) sellvalue FROM  morder r
        LEFT JOIN sale s ON  r.saleid = s.id
        WHERE r.productid = 30340
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: If you run the select statement on it's own do you get a result?

Comment: How come your where have `s.invoicestatus = 'Approved'` but your sum have `s.invoicestatus = 'Active'` the result should be 0 not null. so your  query probably dont return any row

Comment: @P.Salmon, I got result with the select statement. s.invoicestatus is my mistake. But that does not solved the problem either.

Comment: @fancyPants, thanks. but how? I hope you have a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need test your code from basic to complex. Add one thing each time until you found the problem.

Starting with this basic function. I can return the value so the function structure is ok. the problem is the query

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/PIB85630)**

```
CREATE FUNCTION getAmountS(pid INT(11)) RETURNS DOUBLE(12, 2) DETERMINISTIC BEGIN
    DECLARE sellvalue DOUBLE(12, 2) ;
    SELECT 2*pid INTO sellvalue FROM  Table1
    WHERE id = pid;
    RETURN sellvalue;
END;
```

If you add your own data to the rextexter demo we can dig deeper and see where is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have many data. some data return null, I got it right. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As I thought the  problem is the data and not the custom function? Then is this question solve?

Comment: Why is null return instead of zero when there is no data?

Comment: Because SUM (NULL) is NULL